# How to close apps on click of x in the top left

Tags: window-manager

Is there a way to configure the windows manager to close the instance of a program when clicking the "red" x in the top left, if the window is the last one being closed?

Comment: No.  There are utilities out there that more or less do that, but it's not the macOS paradigm.  window != app

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to the dock showing several firefoxes, file explorers and terminals, because I create them by `open /Applications/....app --new`

Comment: And you do that because...?

Comment: That's the only way I've found to open new windows of an app via keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You should write a new question that is the one you actually want answered, namely how to open new windows of running applications.  Doing it for Terminal or Chrome is easy without running another copy of the binary.  I don't have Firefox installed but it should be the same.